# How to Create a Custom Pivot Title Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I would like to be able to create a custom pivot page title style in my application, so that I may use it across multiple pages. Essentially I just want the title of the Pivot to be centered with a certain font size and type. Originally I was using an Image for my title but I really need a text title instead. How might I go about doing this? I've already tried setting this within App.xaml and using it within my MainPage.xaml but so far I don't have anything working.

App.xaml (original)

```
<Style x:Key="ApplicationName" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="92.85"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-3,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Assets/ApplicationTitle.png"/>
    </Style>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="mainPagePivotControl" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}">            
        <phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Style="{StaticResource ApplicationName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        ...
</phone:Pivot>
```